# Locked out of DokuWiki on localhost

Tags: dokuwiki

I set up DokuWiki on `localhost` just to collect some notes.

Alas, I am locked out, can't remmember my password and sending a recovery email doesn't work.

Since I will only use this locally, I need only one user, with admin rights, and no password checking. Can that be done by manually editting the config files?

Comment: Perhaps [this DokuWiki forum link](https://forum.dokuwiki.org/thread/2778) may help.

Comment: Thnaks, I had already found it, but it didn't help me.  Rereading it, I find that the answer by `dude` does work! Please post this as an answer, and I wil accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [DokuWiki forum thread](https://forum.dokuwiki.org/thread/2778), you should be able to reset the password to DokuWiki by changing `users.auth.php`.

For the current stable version of DokuWiki (`2018-04-22b "Greebo"`), this file is located under the `conf` folder.

To reset the password, replace any existing admin login with:

```
admin:$1$4fd0ad31$.cId7p1uxI4a.RcrH81On0:DokuWiki Administrator:mail@host.com:admin,user
```

Then log in with the username `admin` and password `admin`.

Comment: You saved my bacon (and eggs)

Comment: Glad to help. =)